# How to find the error value in sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am inserting values from one table to another table. There are 100000 records in the table. But when I start to insert value from one table to another table there is a problem in any row in my data. I don't know where exactly is that. So how can I know that in which row value is error because the insert statement not complete? After error this stop nothing insert in table.
This is simple statement that I use:

```
INSERT INTO Person (FirstName, LastName,Email)
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email
FROM Person.Contact
```

Comment: do you have any error message?

Comment: There is a table Person in the schema dbo and there is a table Contact in the schema Person? What constraints are imposes on `dbo.Person` (null, primary key, foreign key, unique, check, triggers)? Please add a full create table for `dbo.Person` plus error messages. To answer your question shortly: you have to check which rows of `Person.Contact` violate any of the constraints from `dbo.Person`.

Comment: Related Connect Item Request [new virtual table: errors. It would analogous to the deleted and inserted tables](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/774754/new-virtual-table-errors-it-would-analogous-to-the-deleted-and-inserted-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quesion is hard to understand, but the usual suspects are:

1. Attempting to insert Null into a non-nullable column
2. Foreign Key violations
3. Constraint violations.
4. Attempting to insert wrong datatype.

Please edit you question to add error message.

Comment: if any problem in data in the table how can i know where is the problem means in that row of table

Answer (score 1):

Without any additional information on the constraints imposed on the target table a very general, slow solution would be

1. a cursor loop over the selected rows
2. insert any row within [try/catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175976%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
3. on exception output row and error message

For a specific answer to your problem provide more information.

An alternative method is to use SSIS: here you can provide a separate channel for the erroneous rows. This channel can be lead to a separate table collecting all rows causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `Person` is the name of your schema, so maybe you mean

```
INSERT INTO Person.Person (FirstName, LastName,Email)
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email
FROM   Person.Contact
```

Comment: if any problem in data in the table how can i know where is the problem means in that row of table

Comment: in the error message, question, how do you know that there was an error in your `INSERT` statement?